# Elastic Search Node.js client - Routing Error

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

We have elastic hosted on GCP.  I'm getting an error when I try to simply post a document.  I'm using their node.js package, and I'm stuck with the following error:

```
PS C:\Projects\foo> node --experimental-modules --unhandled-rejections=strict app.js
(node:19356) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
(node:19356) ExperimentalWarning: Conditional exports is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
Posting to Elastic => 5f91dfb0c64004000aab6c9b
C:\Projects\foo\node_modules\@elastic\elasticsearch\lib\Transport.js:257
          const error = new ResponseError(result)
                        ^

ResponseError: Response Error
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\foo\node_modules\@elastic\elasticsearch\lib\Transport.js:257:25)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  name: 'ResponseError',
  meta: {
    body: { error: 'Routing Error. The path you have requested is invalid.' },
    statusCode: 404,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      server: 'Jetty(9.4.30.v20200611)',
      'x-cloud-request-id': 'srCq9DMFQVWuGsdXxgWhjA',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-found-handling-cluster': '[Removed]',
      'x-found-handling-instance': 'instance-0000000001',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-request-id': 'a2696b33-e4dc-4dfc-a8b1-f7ec17906ff7',
      'x-runtime': '0.010689',
      'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
      date: 'Mon, 09 Nov 2020 21:28:28 GMT',
      'content-length': '66'
    },
    meta: {
      context: null,
      request: [Object],
      name: 'elasticsearch-js',
      connection: [Object],
      attempts: 0,
      aborted: false
    }
  }
}
```

I have the client set up as follows

```
   const client = new Client({
        node: 'https://[REMOVED].ent-search.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io',
        auth: {
          apiKey: 'Bearer private-[REMOVED]'
        }
    });
```

Then I attempt to send a json file as an array to Elastic.

```
    client.helpers.bulk({
    datasource: posts,
    onDocument(doc) {
      return {
        create: {_index: 'my-index', _id: elasticPost.id}
      };
     }
   });
```

Update:

***The JSON names MUST be lowercase.***  For example:

Doesn't Work:

```
{
   "Id":  123456
}
```

Works:

```
{
   "id": 123456
}
```

Another thing may have to do with needing the cloud ID from Elastic, I'm not sure if this is required as well, but the lowercase allowed me to upload our document directly into Elastic.

Comment: Which version ES are you running on GCP and which version of the node.js library are you using? Also can you update your question with the full error you're getting?

Comment: Also I think you have one too many `create` in what you return from `onDocument`

Comment: @Val app-search-node is 7.9.0, elasticsearch is 7.9.1.  Using ES Version 6.  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: The library versions should match the ES version. If you're running ES 6 (old version), you cannot use the latest versions of the client libraries.

Comment: I will check it out, and if that doesn't work, we'll go back to the API.  I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON names MUST be lowercase. For example:

Doesn't Work:

```
{
   "Id":  123456,
   "userName": "Dave2118"
}
```

Works:

```
{
   "id": 123456,
   "username": "Dave2118"
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: In what scenario is camelCase not allowed? camelcase works fine on storing docs. So, is that recommendation for searching docs or anything else?

Comment: They may have fixed that now.  I haven't worked with Elastic in a while.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have one too many `create` in the command you return from `onDocument`. The command you can return is described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html):

So, by removing one `create` layer, it should work:

```
client.helpers.bulk({
 datasource: posts,
 onDocument(doc) {
  return {
    create: {_index: 'my-index', _id: elasticPost.id}
  };
 }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Looking at the host name `*.ent-search.*`, it looks like you're using the `elasticsearch` client to try to connect to the Enterprise search backend, that cannot work as the latter doesn't support the `_bulk` API.

If you connect to an AppSearch backend, you can't use the the `_bulk` endpoint (i.e. `client.helpers.bulk()`). Instead, you need to add documents through the AppSearch [Documents API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/7.9/documents.html). Feel free to share more info on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This wasn't the answer, I've posted what I found in the original Question.  Thank you Val for responding, you get the points for helping.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Still weird that the ES client connected to the AppSearch endpoint can hit the bulk endpoint

Comment: This is one of those things I hate about programming, you go way down a path, and it ends up being something simple, which I figured.  I remember spending 8 hours in a computer lab in college trying to fix an error when a peer figures out I'm missing a semi-colin in 2 minutes.

Comment: So basically, this is this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/7.9/schema.html
`Name can only contain lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores`? Great catch!

Comment: Yes.  The National Parks example they use had all lowercase.  It was working and I couldn't figure out why.  I was able to post some keypairs, but I couldn't figure out why some other ones won't work.  I didn't see that link and wish I would have a month ago.  :)

Comment: My bad, I knew but I obviously overlooked that (even though there was no sample data in your question), thinking it was just a configuration problem.

Comment: I should have posted an example of my json, no big deal, thanks again for your help, Val.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, the elastic docs could be a lot clearer sometimes regarding the "normal" api and the appSearch.